# how to reset variable value in JTextField java

Tags: java, swing

I try to make a menu system, and I need to know how I can restart `JTextField`, so that by entering "x" number it shows me another menu, and you can continue browsing between the menus

```java
    JTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String Cap = JTextField.getText();
        switch (Cap) {
            case "1":
                paintConsole("Menu1");
                JTextField.setText("");
                // In this site is my problem, I don't know how to reset a JTextField. PLEASE HELP ME 
                Cap = JTextField.getText();
                if (Cap.equals("1")) {
                    paintConsole("Menu9");
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                paintConsole("Menu2");
                break;
            case "3":
                paintConsole("Menu3");
                break;
            case "4":
                paintConsole("Menu4");
            case "5":
                paintConsole("Menu5");
                break;
            case "6":
                paintConsole("Menu6");
                break;
        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: `String Cap = JTextField.getText();` is worrying.  Besides you call `setText("")` before you get the value from the field, which seems to counterintuitive. I'm also wondering why you'd both using a `JTextField` for this job and wouldn't just use buttons or a `JTabbedBar` or a `JMenuBar` or a `JToolBar` or a combination of them

Comment: Sorry friend, I don't know how to explain my problem.
I don't know how I can get the value of JTextField again, I try to make a menu through an interface, and when the user presses "1" it shows a menu with different options listed, and when I press "1" again or any other number , show another menu

Comment: I'm with @MadProgrammer that this code really doesn't make sense. But in addition you appear to be trying to make instance method calls on the JTextField class, as if those methods were static, and so this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: This question looks to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely. Consider telling us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: Ok guys. I am trying to make a menu system, and the following happens:
It is assumed that the program shows me a user interface where there is a JEditorPane and a JTextField, so when executing it it shows a menu of options in the EditorPane and the user has to enter a number in the TextField to choose the options, so there I am Well, but when I get to the second menu it doesn't let me, because the variable that stores the user's input doesn't reset, I mean the TextField, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I'm new in programing, and my learning is empirical,sorry if I don't explain myself well

Comment: *"I'm new in programing"* GUIs are an advanced topic. Best to sort out this sort of stuff in command line apps.

Comment: :/ Too bad you think so, the programming is to challenge yourself every day, and not stay in the loop of the command line app's

Comment: What @AndrewThompson meant (I think) is to divide and conquer -- to break the problem down into its most basic essence, and then debug and fix the logic before trying to hang a complex GUI around it.

Comment: Tip: Add @HovercraftFullOfEels (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. Note that throwing complex APIs into the mix makes problems harder to debug. But from the description so far provided, take heed of Hov's comment re the XY problem. It seems you are trying to do something (which *might* be simple) in a very complicated and counter-intuitive way.

Comment: Oh, and also .. Look at [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Comment: Ok guys thank you very much for the comments, I will continue studying to someday give the answer hahaha